# Case_when dplyr

Tags: r, quantmod, case-when, tidyquant

I am trying to create a buy/sell signal.  I am trying to assign the signal using a case_when statement.  I created several new columns using tidyquant TQ_MUTATE in a previous step.  This only assigns the "possible up" and "possible down" signals.

What am I doing wrong?

df_with_decisions <- test %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  mutate(

```
signal = case_when(
   (EMA_9 > EMA_55) ~ "possible up",
  (EMA_9 > EMA_55 && EVWMA_9 > EMA_55) ~ "watch upward",
  (EMA_9 > EMA_55 && EMA_21 >= EMA_55 && EVWMA_9 > EMA_55) ~ "buy",
  (EMA_9 > EMA_55 && EMA_21 >= EMA_55 && EVWMA_9 > EMA_55 && EVWMA_21 > EMA_55) ~ "strong_buy",
  EMA_9 < EMA_55 ~ "possible down",
  (EMA_9 < EMA_55 && EVWMA_9 < EMA_55) ~ "watch downward",
  (EMA_9 < EMA_55 && EMA_21 <= EMA_55 && EVWMA_9 < EMA_55) ~ "sell",
  (EMA_9 < EMA_55 && EMA_21 <= EMA_55 && EVWMA_9 < EMA_55 && EVWMA_21 < EMA_55) ~ "strong_sell",
  ),

previous_signal = lag(signal, 1),

decision = case_when(
  signal == previous_signal ~ "hold",
  TRUE ~ signal    )  )
```

Comment: Can you change the `&&` to `&`

Comment: There is a logical error too I think. If EMA_9 > EMA_55, it will not get to the other options that include the same condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logical error too.

```
case_when(
  (5 > 3) ~ "Hi",
  ((5 > 3) & (6 > 3)) ~ "Hello"
)
```

This will not print Hello

Comment: So, does that mean I am doing something wrong or is it the way that R uses case_when?  I am still trying to learn R.  Would it be better to use an if_else/if statement

Comment: Case when is expected to execute one of many possibilities. When one of the options match, it is inefficient to look further. You may get by in some languages by placing more specific expressions ahead of more general expressions. But that is dangerous. In this case, if, else if is better (with more specific cases ahead of more generic cases). For example, if (EMA_9 > EMA_55 & EMA_21 >= EMA_55 & EVWMA_9 > EMA_55 & EVWMA_21 > EMA_55) {...} else if (EMA_9 > EMA_55 & EMA_21 >= EMA_55 & EVWMA_9 > EMA_55) else if ...

Comment: I really appreciate the help. It clarifies things.

Answer (score 1):

The issue would be that `&&` which returns a single TRUE/FALSE output instead of logical vector of the same length as input

```html
test %>%
     group_by(symbol) %>%
     mutate(

signal = case_when(
   (EMA_9 > EMA_55) ~ "possible up",
  (EMA_9 > EMA_55 & EVWMA_9 > EMA_55) ~ "watch upward",
  (EMA_9 > EMA_55 & EMA_21 >= EMA_55 & EVWMA_9 > EMA_55) ~ "buy",
  (EMA_9 > EMA_55 & EMA_21 >= EMA_55 & EVWMA_9 > EMA_55 & EVWMA_21 > EMA_55) ~ "strong_buy",
  EMA_9 < EMA_55 ~ "possible down",
  (EMA_9 < EMA_55 & EVWMA_9 < EMA_55) ~ "watch downward",
  (EMA_9 < EMA_55 & EMA_21 <= EMA_55 & EVWMA_9 < EMA_55) ~ "sell",
  (EMA_9 < EMA_55 && EMA_21 <= EMA_55 & EVWMA_9 < EMA_55 & EVWMA_21 < EMA_55) ~ "strong_sell",
  ),

previous_signal = lag(signal, 1),

decision = case_when(
  signal == previous_signal ~ "hold",
  TRUE ~ signal    )  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the brackets as much as you think it was helpful. I always finish with TRUE at the end of case_when. Mutate is such a milestone in tandem with Case_when.
This is an example:

```
mutate(Intensidad_guerra = case_when(
     (MD_P2_filt$battle_type %in% c("pitched battle") | MD_P2_filt$battle_type %in% c("siege")) ~ "nivel alto",
                                  MD_P2_filt$battle_type %in% c("ambush")  ~"nivel medio",
                                  TRUE ~ "nivel bajo"))
```